# How to import a .mhx file into blender using a python script

Tags: python, scripting, makehuman

I need to write a python script in order to import .mhx file and management it. I don't if it is possible to do that or no? Any help?

Comment: Make human comes with a script to import MHX files into blender. there are tutorials at the main website http://www.makehuman.org/documentation

Comment: If this is a question about python you may better ask it on the main SO. Maybe you should edit your question to "how can I export MakeHuman files to Blender"

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the [make human blender tools](http://download.tuxfamily.org/makehuman/releases/1.0.2/blendertools-1.0.2-all.zip) from the make human website.
2. Open the zip. It will create a "blendertools" folder where you opened it.
3. Install the make human scene importer script:
   blendertools\mhx_importer\import_scene_mhx.py
4. Once the plugin is installed, this command will become available to you via python:

   bpy.ops.import_scene.makehuman_mhx(filter_glob="*.mhx", filepath="", scale=1, advanced=False, enforce=True, mesh=True, proxy=True, cage=False, clothes=True, shapekeys=True, drivers=False, diamond=False, rigify=True)

Comment: Thanks. I guess not all of these parameters are needed? Some of them must be set by default

Comment: Sure, every param there has a default value, though I'd make sure to provide a value for the filepath param :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the [blender-addons](https://github.com/jaredly/blender-addons) repository?
There are quite a few resources available for you to dive in, like this one for example:

[io_import_scene_mhx.py](https://github.com/jaredly/blender-addons/blob/master/io_import_scene_mhx.py)

The `ImportMhx` class at line `2958` gives you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons the newer version of MakeHuman (1.1.x) have removed the .mhx export option! Somebody has developed the MHX2 plugin which you can download from [here](https://thomasmakehuman.wordpress.com/mhx2-documentation/download/) or from [the BitBucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/src/default/). Then following the instructions on the README file:

- copy the 9_export_mhx2 folder to the MakeHuman plugins folder. For example on macOS it is in `/Applications/MakeHuman.app/Contents/Resources/plugins`
- copy the import_runtime_mhx2 folder to the Blender addons folder. On my macOS it is on `/Users/userName/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.79/scripts/addons`
- The you may follow [these instruction](https://thomasmakehuman.wordpress.com/mhx2-documentation/import-into-blender/)s to activate the plugin on Blender

After that you can export as mhx2 and then directly import in Blender.